# How to install ngrx store version 12 with all required packages?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I need version 12 because currently project is on angular CLI 12.
If i try to just install NGRX i always getting version 13, when i try install version 12, i missing effects, actions and other stuff. How to get normal ngrx 12?

#Update1

Currently i had error:

> Cannot find module '@ngrx/store' or its corresponding type
> declarations

Answer (score 0):

For the installation, I've been using NGRX since angular 6 and you always had to install the submodules separately. In [the documentation page of ngrx](https://ngrx.io/docs) you'll see these submodules and you click them open you'll see the link for installation.

[image: submodules]

With cli6+ you will need to

```
ng add @ngrx/store@latest
ng add @ngrx/store-devtools@latest
ng add @ngrx/router-store@latest
ng add @ngrx/entity@latest
ng add @ngrx/schematics@latest
ng add @ngrx/component-store@latest
```

If you need an older version replace the word `latest` with the version you need. [ref for versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/store)

Note that the reason that they split this is so you the user could install only the parts you really need. It's therefor recommended to first think about what you'll need and then add that part of NGRX.

If you want to use the devtools you'll need to install the [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) for redux devtools. This is quite handy in development because it stores the state and you can roll back, see payloads, see actions, etc...

[image]

If this is just a learning project, you can just install everything.

Here's an [example application mentioned in the NGRX documentation](https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-contacts-app-example/tree/master/src/app).